# Run command with sudo

Tags: linux

I'm trying to start/stop service with php. I have added

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

to /etc/sudousers. When I run command (like sudo ls /) as a regular user it run successfuly.

Here is the code in my php file

```
exec("sudo /etc/init.d/service stop");
```

When I request this file in browser and then check in terminal the process is not stopped. 
What I miss ?

Comment: Apache user is www-data.

Comment: is www-data inside %admin group?

Comment: What you mean. Can you give me an example ?

Comment: He means add the www-data user to the admin group, that'll be a sys admin task on your server, unrelated to PHP.

Comment: I have added this www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL line to sudousers. Now I can stop/start the process but the problem is that I get Z    15:43   0:00 [process] <defunct> in ps list when I try to start the process.

Comment: Did you use visudo to change the sudoers file?

Answer (score 0):

The "%" in `%admin`, at the beginning of your sudoers line, means "group" — i.e. "admin group".  If the apache user is not in this group then this line won't apply to it.

Try

```
    www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Note that this is **not safe at all**.  You should **restrict the commands available** for this particular user.  This can be done either by giving them explicitely or by defining a `Cmnd_Alias` (see `man sudoers` and examples in `visudo`).